# Occasional IDE error when running Flutter app on iPhone simulator. FlutterApp.setLaunchMode must not be null

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Sometimes when I run my Flutter app on the iPhone simulator via Android Studio I get the IDE error "FlutterApp.setLaunchMode must not be null" full stack trace below. How can I fix this? Thanks.

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$5.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:223)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:197)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$SimpleOutputReader.onTextAvailable(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:198)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.sendText(BaseOutputReader.java:202)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.processInput(BaseOutputReader.java:186)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.readAvailableNonBlocking(BaseOutputReader.java:105)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.readAvailable(BaseDataReader.java:85)
>     at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.doRun(BaseDataReader.java:163)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader$1$1.run(BaseDataReader.java:66)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:229)
>     at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader$1.run(BaseDataReader.java:63)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter
>   'launchMode' of io/flutter/run/daemon/FlutterApp.setLaunchMode must
>   not be null   at
>   io.flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp.$$$reportNull$$$0(FlutterApp.java)
>     at io.flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp.setLaunchMode(FlutterApp.java)
>     at
>   io.flutter.run.daemon.FlutterAppDaemonEventListener.onAppStarting(FlutterApp.java:726)
>     at
>   io.flutter.run.daemon.DaemonEvent$AppStarting.accept(DaemonEvent.java:190)
>     at io.flutter.run.daemon.DaemonEvent.dispatch(DaemonEvent.java:52)
>     at io.flutter.run.daemon.DaemonApi.dispatch(DaemonApi.java:171)     at
>   io.flutter.run.daemon.DaemonApi$1.onTextAvailable(DaemonApi.java:142)
>     ... 20 more

Comment: same for me but for Android, you got any update?

Comment: I turned off my machine all night and i wake up and when i turned it on it works as allways. Perhaps the error lives in memory or in a place like a cache and when it is clear it disappears. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio Flutter Plugin version 33.3, update released Feb.25th 2019 change log indicates:

"Fix an issue with an IllegalArgumentException when running Flutter apps"

I'll report back if the issue persists.

UPDATE: Appears to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

So I have just come across this today also.
I'm running Android Studio and targeting an Android emulator, so it seems to be more core related than target.

..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'launchMode' of io/flutter/run/daemon/FlutterApp.setLaunchMode must not be null

Android Studio 3.3.1
Windows 10 64Bit

I'll edit this as I discover pertinent info.